# An unexpected application of non-trivial combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics, applications

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

> Given two finite sets $A$ and $B$, each containing $s \in \mathbb N$ elements, how many pairs of functions $f \colon A \rightarrow B$ and $g \colon B \rightarrow A$ are there, such that their composition $h = g \circ f$ has no fixed points?

**THE ORIGIN OF THE PROBLEM**

> It is highly improbable that two people could happen to like each other by chance.

Which, under the following assumptions:

- We are considering a group of $2n$ people with $n$ men and $n$ women;
- Each person likes exactly one person of the opposite sex with equal probability;

reduces to

> Given two finite sets $A$ and $B$, each containing $n \in \mathbb N$ elements, and two arbitrary functions $f \colon A \rightarrow B$ and $g \colon B \rightarrow A$, what is the expected number of pairs of elements $(a \in A, b \in B)$ such that $f(a) = b$ and $g(b) = a$?

**WHAT I HAVE DONE**

Here I am using $E$ for expectation, $P$ for probability and $N$ for number.

$$E(\text{number of pairs}) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n k \cdot P(\text{there are exactly }k\text{ pairs})$$

$$P(\text{there are exactly }k\text{ pairs}) = \frac {N(\text{situations with }k\text{ pairs})} {N(\text{total situations})}$$

$$N(\text{total situations}) = (n^n)^2,$$

because there are $n^n$ functions from $A$ to $B$ and the same number in the reverse direction.

$$ \begin{aligned} 
N & (\text{situations with }k\text{ pairs}) = \\
 & = N(\text{pairs of functions }(f \colon A \rightarrow B, g \colon B \rightarrow A) \\
 & \quad \text{ whose composition has exactly }k\text{ fixed points}) = \\
 & = \sum [\text{over selections of }k\text{ elements from both }A\text{ and }B] \\
 & \quad N(\text{pairs of functions whose composition is identity only on the selection}) = \\
 & = {\binom {n} {k}}^2 \cdot k! \cdot N(\text{pairs of functions on two sets containing } \\
 & \quad s = n - k\text{ elements whose composition has no fixed points})
\end{aligned} $$

This is how I reduced the original problem to the problem in question. If the solution to that problem was $N(s)$, the answer to the original problem would be

$$E(\text{number of pairs}) = \frac {1} {(n^n)^2} \sum\limits_{k=0}^n k \cdot {\binom {n} {k}}^2 \cdot k! \cdot N(n - k)$$

**WHAT I TRIED TO DO**

Approach: fix $g$, count $f$s.

$$ \begin{multline}
N(s) = \sum [\text{over all functions }g \colon B \rightarrow A] \\
N(\text{functions }f \colon A \rightarrow B\text{ such that the composition }h = g \circ f \\
\text{ has no fixed points})
\end{multline} $$

Problem: all such $f$s have to send every $a$ to anywhere but $g^{-1}(a)$. Therefore, there are $\prod\limits_{a \in A} (n - \left|g^{-1}(a)\right|)$ such functions. The sets $\left\{g^{-1}(a)\right\}_{a \in A}$ form a partition of $B$. The obvious next idea is to classify all $g$s based on that partition, but the formulas start to get really scary.

**UPD:** I wrote a simulation that actually counted directly the expectation for $n=1..5$ (the $O(n\cdot(n^n)^2)$ approach). The expected value is always exactly 1. I have no idea how to interpret that, given the crazy formula for expectation.

*I would mostly appreciate an idea for an approach, not a complete solution.*

Comment: Your expression for the number of situations with exactly $k$ pairs (the one involving $N(n-k)$) is wrong, as the remaining $n-k$ men and remaining $n-k$ women, while having no mutual likings, can still like any of the $k$ women or $k$ men chosen as mutually liking. (I've posted an answer with the correct expression.) So the answer to $E(\text{number of pairs})$ (which is $1$) is not really a reduction to $\Pr(\text{no fixed points})$, though if you do it right and add up the "crazy formula for expectation" you indeed get $1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As we deal with arbitrary functions $f \colon A \to B$ and $g \colon B \to A$, there is nothing special to be got by taking $\lvert A \rvert = \lvert B \rvert = n$, so we'll answer the question more generally: Let's say we have $\lvert A \rvert = m$ men, and $\lvert B \rvert = w$ women. This adds no real difficulty to the calculations, and instead makes some expressions clearer. For your case, just set $m = w = n$.

The random model we assume throughout is that we pick any of the $w^m m^w$ pairs of functions $(f, g)$ with equal probability.

We will prove below that, under this random model,

- the **expected** number of fixed points of $f \circ g$ or $g \circ f$, or in other words, the expected number of pairs of men and women who like each other, is $1$, and more generally,
- for any $k$, the probability that this number of fixed points is exactly $k$ is a quantity that we can calculate exactly, and approaches $\dfrac{1}{k!e}$ as $m, w \to \infty$. In other words, the distribution of the number of mutually liking pairs approaches a [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with mean $1$.

---

- *"If I like someone, what is the probability that they like me back?"*
  Answer: $\dfrac1m$ if I'm a man, $\dfrac1w$ if I'm a woman.

For any $f\colon A \to B$ and any $a \in A$, if $f(a) = b \in B$, then the probability over random functions $g\colon B\to A$ that $g(b) = a$ is exactly $\dfrac1m$, as $g(b)$ takes on all $\left\vert{A}\right\vert = m$ values with equal probability. And as the probability is the same for each specific $f$, it remains the same when $f$ too is chosen at random.

Similarly for the women.

---

- *"What is the expected number of men who are liked back by the women they like?"*
  Answer: $1$.

This is by linearity of expectation: for any $f$, we have 
$$\operatorname{E}\left[\#\{a: g(f(a)) = a\}\right] = \sum_{a \in A} \Pr(g(f(a)) = m \frac1m = 1.$$
And as the expectation is the same for each individual $f$, it is also the same when $f$ itself is picked at random.

---

- *"What is the expected number of women who are liked back by the men they like?"*
  Answer: $1$.

By symmetry / a similar calcuation.

---

- *"What is the expected number of pairs of (men, women) who like each other?"*
  Answer: $1$.

The number of mutually liking pairs is of course the same as the either of the two numbers just previously considered.

So this actually **answers your original question:** the expected number of pairs $(a, b)$ such that $f(a) = b$ and $g(b) = a$ is exactly $1$.

---

It remains to answer the question you "reduced" it to (which as we will see is not exactly a reduction), about the number of pairs of functions $f \colon A \to B$ and $g \colon B \to A$ such that $g \circ f$ has no fixed points. Let's sidle up to it by inches.

---

- *"For a given set of $k$ men, what is the probability that they are all liked back by the women they like?*"
  Answer: $\dfrac{\binom{w}{k}k!}{w^k m^k} = \dfrac{w^{\underline k}}{w^k m^k}$.

Given $f$ and $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k$, what is the probability that $g(f(a_i)) = a_i$ for all $1 \le i \le k$? This probability depends on $f$. Clearly a necessary condition that all the $a_i$'s like distinct women: if two of them like the same woman, there is no way they can *both* be liked back. But for any $f$ where this necessary condition holds, then the events of each of them being liked back are independent; each of the men is liked back with probability $1/m$, giving probability $\dfrac1{m^k}$ that they are all liked back.

The number of functions $f$ satisfying this distinctness condition is $\displaystyle \binom{w}{k}k! w^{m-k}$. Thus the probability when taken over all functions $f$ is 
$$\frac{\frac{1}{m^k} \cdot \binom{w}{k}k! w^{m-k} + 0 \cdot \text{(the rest)}}{w^m} = \frac{\binom{w}{k}k!}{m^k w^k}$$
and so the number of such pairs of functions $(f, g)$ is $w^{m-k}m^{w-k}\binom{w}{k}k!$.

(We could also have calculated this directly: the function $f$ on the $a_i$'s can be picked in $\binom{w}{k}k!$ ways, on the other $a$'s in $w^{m-k}$ ways, and $g$ in $m^{w-k}$ ways.)

We can also use the [falling factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FallingFactorial.html) notation: $w^{\underline k} = \binom{w}{k}k!$.

---

Finally we can answer the question:

- *"What is the probability that no one is liked back?"*

That is, what is the probability that $g \circ f$ has no fixed points? Let the set $L \subseteq A$ denote the set of fixed points of $g \circ f$: the set of **l**ucky men who are **l**iked back. We have calculated, in the previous question, the probability that $A_k \subseteq L$, for any particular subset $A_k$ of $A$ having size $k$. Thus, by the inclusion-exclusion principle,

$$\begin{align}
\Pr(L = \emptyset) 
&= \Pr(\emptyset \subseteq L) - \binom{m}{1}\Pr(A_1 \subseteq L) + \binom{m}{2}\Pr(A_2 \subseteq L) - \binom{m}{3}\Pr(A_3 \subseteq L) + \dots \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k \binom{m}{k}\binom{w}{k} k! m^{-k}w^{-k}
\end{align}$$

Using the falling factorial notation, the above can also be written as
$$P_{m, w, 0} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{m^{\underline k}}{m^k} \frac{w^{\underline k}}{w^k} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$

I changed the upper limit of the sum to $\infty$ instead of $m$, to highlight that the expression is symmetric in $m$ and $w$: note that when $k > m$ we have $m^{\underline k} = 0$, and when $k > w$ we have $w^{\underline k} = 0$, so the terms in the sum are nonzero only up to $k = \min(m, w)$.

---

For the particular case when $m = w = n$, the number of pairs of functions $(f, g)$ such that $g \circ f$ has no fixed points is
$$\begin{align}
T_n 
&= n^{2n} P_{n,n,0} \\
&= n^{2n} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}^2 k! n^{-2k} \\
&= n^{2n} \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{n^{\underline k}}{n^k}\right)^2 \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}
\end{align}$$

This number $T_n$, for $n = 0, 1, 2, \dots$, takes the values
$$1, 0, 2, 156, 16920, 2764880, 650696400, 210105425628, 89425255439744, 48588905856409920, 32845298636854828800, 27047610425293718239100, 26664178085975252011318272, 31009985808408471580603417296, 42017027730087624384021945067520, 65618911142809749231767185516069500, \dots$$
and is surprisingly not in OEIS, nor are the corresponding probabilities $P_{n,n,0} = \dfrac{T_n}{n^{2n}}$ which are

$$1, 0, \frac18, \frac{52}{243}, \frac{2215}{8192}, \frac{552976}{1953125}, \dots$$
$$\approx 1, 0, 0.125, 0.214, 0.258, 0.283, 0.299, 0.310, 0.318, 0.324, 0.328, 0.332, 0.335, 0.338, 0.340, 0.342, \dots$$

However, we will prove below that $P_{n, n, 0}$ approaches $\dfrac{1}{e} \approx 0.367879\dots$ as $n \to \infty$. Note that even before the proof, we can find this plausible, for two reasons:

- when the factor $\frac{n^{\underline k}}{n^k}$ (squared) which is close to $1$ is removed, the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$ does indeed converge to $e^{-1}$ as $n \to \infty$ (this will be how we prove it), and
- each $a \in A$ is *not* a fixed point with probability $1 - \frac1n$, so the independence approximation (treating these events as independent even though they are not) gives the probability of no fixed points to be $\left(1 - \frac1n \right)^n \to e^{-1}$, and perhaps this independence approximation gets better for large $n$.

---

Extending the above we can also answer

- *"What is the probability that exactly $k$ men are liked back?"*

Your expression for the number of such pairs of functions (on which hinges calling the previous problem a reduction) was $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}^2 k! T_{n-k}$, meant to count the number of functions $(f, g)$ such that $k$ pairs are mutually liking and there are no fixed points on the remaing $n-k$ men and women. But this is **not correct**, as (for instance) the function on the remaining $m-k$ elements of $A$ is not constrained to take on values from the remaining $w-k$ elements of $B$ alone (it can also take values from the same $k$ elements already picked).

The right expression is given by the inclusion-exclusion principle: given a particular set $A_k$ of $k$ men, the probability that these are exactly the men liked back is

$$\begin{align}
\Pr(L = A_k)
&= \Pr(A_k \subseteq L) - \binom{m-k}{1}\Pr(A_{k+1} \subseteq L) + \binom{m-k}{2}\Pr(A_{k+2} \subseteq L) - \dots \\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{m-k} (-1)^r \binom{m-k}{r} \binom{w}{k+r}\frac{(k+r)!}{m^{k+r}w^{k+r}} \\
&= \sum_{l=k}^m (-1)^{l-k} \binom{m-k}{l-k} \binom{w}{l} \frac{l!}{m^l w^l}
\end{align}$$

and the probability got by choosing all sets of size $k$ is $\displaystyle \binom{m}{k}$ times that:

$$\begin{align}
P_{m, w, k} 
&= \sum_{l=k}^m (-1)^{l-k} \binom{m}{k} \binom{m-k}{l-k} \binom{w}{l}\frac{l!}{m^l w^l} \\
&= \sum_{l=k}^m (-1)^{l-k} \binom{l}{k} \binom{m}{l} \binom{w}{l} \frac{l!}{m^l w^l} \\
&= \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{l=k}^m \frac{m^{\underline l}}{m^l} \frac{w^{\underline l}}{w^l} \frac{(-1)^{l-k}}{(l-k)!} \\
&= \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{m^{\underline {k+r}}}{m^{k+r}} \frac{w^{\underline {k+r}}}{w^{k+r}} \frac{(-1)^r}{r!}
\end{align}$$

(again we've changed the upper limit of the sum, with no change in value).
Note that when $k=0$, we recover our earlier expression for $P_{m, w, 0}$. We will prove below that $P_{m, w, k} \to \frac{1}{k!e}$ as $m, w \to \infty$.

---

- *"What is the expected number of men who are liked back?"*

We already answered this earlier (it's $1$), but using the above, it is also equal to

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^m k P_{m, w, k} 
&= \sum_{k=0}^m k \sum_{r=k}^{m} (-1)^{r-k} \binom{r}{k} \binom{m}{r} \binom{w}{r}\frac{r!}{m^rw^r} \\
&= \sum_{r=0}^m \binom{m}{r}\binom{w}{r}\frac{r!}{m^rw^r} (-1)^r \sum_{k=0}^r k\binom{r}{k} (-1)^{k}
\\ &= 1
\end{align}$$
(as the inner sum is nonzero only for $r=0$), as expected.

---

Finally, the promised proof about $P_{m, w, k}$. Suppose that $m$ and $w$ both go to infinity, in any which way — the relative rates don't matter. We can imagine them given by a sequence $(m_i, w_i)$, with the only property being needed that $m_i \to \infty$ and $w_i \to \infty$ as $i \to \infty$.

Then, for every fixed $k$ and $r$, we have $\displaystyle \frac{m_i^{\underline {k+r}}}{m_i^{k+r}} \frac{w_i^{\underline {k+r}}}{w_i^{k+r}} \to 1$ as $i \to \infty$ (and moreover is less than $1$ in absolute value), so by the dominated convergence theorem for series (see [here](http://www.math.hmc.edu/~krieger/analysisresults.pdf) for instance; idea via [user Etienne here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/726586/205)), we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{i \to \infty} P_{m_i, w_i, k} 
&= \lim_{i \to \infty} \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{m_i^{\underline {k+r}}}{m^{k+r}} \frac{w_i^{\underline {k+r}}}{w^{k+r}} \frac{(-1)^r}{r!} \\
&= \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^r}{r!} \\
&= \frac{1}{k!e}
\end{align}$$

which proves our claims about the limiting distribution.

---

Some data: For $0 \le n \le 7$, below is the number $n^{2n}P_{n, n, k}$ of pairs of functions $f,g$ for $m=w=n$, such that $f \circ g$ has exactly $k$ fixed points.

```
0 {0: 1}
1 {0: 0, 1: 1}
2 {0: 2, 1: 12, 2: 2}
3 {0: 156, 1: 423, 2: 144, 3: 6}
4 {0: 16920, 1: 33184, 2: 13968, 3: 1440, 4: 24}
5 {0: 2764880, 1: 4581225, 2: 2088800, 3: 316200, 4: 14400, 5: 120}
6 {0: 650696400, 1: 973830816, 2: 460350000, 3: 85521600, 4: 6231600, 5: 151200, 6: 720}
7 {0: 210105425628, 1: 293840040823, 2: 141537806928, 3: 29771976150, 4: 2849330400, 5: 116794440, 6: 1693440, 7: 5040}
```

Next, (some of) the corresponding probabilities $P_{n, n, k}$:

```
1 {0: 0.000, 1: 1.00}
2 {0: 0.125, 1: 0.750, 2: 0.125}
3 {0: 0.214, 1: 0.580, 2: 0.198, 3: 0.00823}
4 {0: 0.258, 1: 0.506, 2: 0.213, 3: 0.0220, 4: 0.000366}
5 {0: 0.283, 1: 0.469, 2: 0.214, 3: 0.0324, 4: 0.00147, 5: 0.0000123}
6 {0: 0.299, 1: 0.447, 2: 0.211, 3: 0.0393, 4: 0.00286, 5: 0.0000695, 6: 3.31e-7}
7 {0: 0.310, 1: 0.433, 2: 0.209, 3: 0.0439, 4: 0.00420, 5: 0.000172, 6: 2.50e-6, 7: 7.43e-9}
8 {0: 0.318, 1: 0.423, 2: 0.206, 3: 0.0471, 4: 0.00538, 5: 0.000303, 6: 7.70e-6, 7: 7.22e-8, 8: 1.43e-10}
9 {0: 0.324, 1: 0.416, 2: 0.204, 3: 0.0494, 4: 0.00638, 5: 0.000444, 6: 0.0000160, 7: 2.72e-7, 8: 1.74e-9, 9: 2.42e-12}
10 {0: 0.328, 1: 0.410, 2: 0.202, 3: 0.0511, 4: 0.00723, 5: 0.000586, 6: 0.0000269, 7: 6.62e-7, 8: 7.84e-9, 9: 3.59e-11}
100 {0: 0.364, 1: 0.372, 2: 0.186, 3: 0.0607, 4: 0.0146, 5: 0.00273, 6: 0.000419, 7: 0.0000539, 8: 5.94e-6, 9: 5.69e-7, ...}
1000 {0: 0.368, 1: 0.368, 2: 0.184, 3: 0.0613, 4: 0.0153, 5: 0.00303, 6: 0.000501, 7: 0.0000709, 8: 8.76e-6, 9: 9.59e-7, ...}
```

and for $n = 10000$:

```
10000 {0: 0.36784, 1: 0.36792, 2: 0.18396, 3: 0.061307, 4: 0.015321, 5: 0.0030623, 6: 0.00050997, 7: 0.000072781, 8: 9.0867e-6, 9: 1.0082e-6, ...}
```

Contrast this with the actual Poisson distribution $\frac{1}{k!e}$:

```
{0: 0.36788, 1: 0.36788, 2: 0.18394, 3: 0.061313, 4: 0.015328, 5: 0.0030657, 6: 0.00051094, 7: 0.000072992, 8: 9.1240e-6, 9: 1.0138e-6, ...}
```

So we can see that convergence is rather slow.

Comment: The sequence $1, 0, 2, 156, 16920, 2764880, 650696400, …$ is now in OEIS, as [A284458](https://oeis.org/A284458). (Not sure why I didn't propose it on OEIS immediately after posting this answer…) It links to another later question on this site ([Couple Probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/982134/couple-probability)), and I've proposed an edit on OEIS linking back to this question.

Answer (score 3):

To begin with, the expected number $E(H)$  of hits (first choice matchings) is $1$, and more is true: One  has
$$E(H\,|\, f)=1$$ 
for every individual $f:\>A\to B$.

*Proof.* Assume that an $f$ is given. We have a hit at $b\in B$ when $g(b)\in f^{-1}(\{b\})$. The probability  that this is the case is equal to
$$P(b\,|\, f):={\#f^{-1}(\{b\})\over n}\ .$$
Therefore $E(H\,|\, f)$ becomes
$$E(H\,|\, f)=\sum_{k=1}^n P(b_k\,|\,f)={1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n \#f^{-1}(\{b_k\})=1\ .$$
When $n=5$ there are  $5^{10}=9\,765\,625$ cases in all. Mathematica has found the following probability distribution of $H$:
$$(0.283124, 0.469117, 0.213893, 0.0323789, 0.00147456, 0.000012288)\ .$$
These values are to be interpreted as follows: With $28.3\%$ probability we have no hits, with $46.9\%$ probability exactly one hit, and so on. The last value is $=5!/5^{10}$ and comes from bijective $f$'s with $g=f^{-1}$.

(One might have conjectured that $H$ is approximatively Poisson distributed with mean $1$, but this seems not  to be the case.)

Comment: Great answer, and brilliant idea to compute the expected value directly without worrying about the distribution. In terms of guessing the actual distribution, the result in my answer strongly suggests that $p(H=0)=1-p(H\ge1)=\dfrac{1}{e}$. Does that ring a bell?

Comment: Actually this $H$ does actually tend to a Poisson distribution with mean $1$ (see my answer [below](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713370/an-unexpected-application-of-non-trivial-combinatorics/722961#722961)), so your conjecture was correct. It's just that the convergence is slow.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a not-carefully checked attempt to solve a simpler, related question: What is the probability that there is at least one fixed point. If it's wrong, I hope it at least helps. Perhaps you can then compute the probability of at least two, at least three, etc., and then find the expected value you’re looking for.

For $J\subseteq N=\{1,\dots,n\}$, let $P_J$ be the probability that for a random pair of functions $f,g:N\to N$, $J$ is contained in the set of points fixed by $g\circ f$.

If $|J|=1$, WLOG $J=\{1\}$, and $P_J=\dfrac{1}{n}$. ($g$ must take $f(1)$ to $1$).

If $|J|=2$, WLOG $J=\{1,2\}$. For the set of fixed points to include $J$, it must be the case that $f(1)\ne f(2)$ (probability $\dfrac{n-1}{n}$) and $g(f(i))=i$ for $i=1,2$ (probability $\dfrac{1}{n^2}$. So $P_J=\dfrac{n-1}{n^3}$.

If $J=\{1,\dots,k\}$, it must be the case that $f(1),f(2),\dots,f(k)$ are distinct (probability $\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!\,n^k}$) and $g(f(i))=i$ for $i=1\dots k$ (probability $\dfrac{1}{n^k}$. In this case, $P_J=\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!\,n^{2k}}$.

By inclusion-exclusion, the probability of at least one fixed point is

$${n\choose1}P_{\{1\}}-{n\choose2}P_{\{1,2\}}+{n\choose3}P_{\{1,2,3\}}\cdots \pm {n\choose n}P_{\{1,\dots,n\}} = \sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}{n\choose k} \dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!\,n^{2k}}\textrm.$$

Mathematica evaluates the sum as $1 - n^{-2 n} U(-n, 1, n^2)$, where $U(a,b,z)$ is the confluent hypergeometric function $\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int_0^\infty e^{-zt}t^{a-1}(1+t)^{b-a-1}\,dt$. Mathematica doesn’t find its limit as $n\to\infty$, but it sure looks like it could be $1-\dfrac{1}{e}$, which suggests there might be a much easier formulation of this as a derangement problem.

[image]

Comment: The probability does indeed converge to $1-1/e$, though I don't think it can be formulated as a derangement problem: these probabilities are different and "two steps removed" from $D_n/n!$ (in the sense of [this question I asked here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726376/does-this-really-converge-to-1-e-massaging-a-sum?lq=1)). Also the probability of exactly $k$ fixed points tends to a Poisson distribution, as I managed to (finally) show in [my answer below](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713370/an-unexpected-application-of-non-trivial-combinatorics/722961#722961).

Answer (score 2):

As Steve points out, this can be reformulated as a more standard derangement problem. We can produce all pairs of functions $f \circ g$ as follows. Choose $f \circ g = h$ a derangement of $N =  \{ 1, 2 , \dots, n\}$. Then let $f$ be any bijection you like. This forces $g$ completely. Moreover, all pairs $f, g$ arise like this as clearly both $f$ and $g$ must be bijections.

So the total number of such pairs is just 
$$n! \left[ \frac{n!}{e} \right]$$
where the brackets denote the `nearest integer' function.

**Edit**: This is wrong, thanks to Steve for pointing out my misread of question. Let's try again...

**Edit 2**: The below is also false unfortunately. In particular I don't consider the case that $h|K$ is not a bijection. Nor do I count the ways that $h$ can be decomposed. The idea might be salvageable, but will probably be somewhat complicated.

Fix some $h = f \circ g$ and denote its image by $K = \{ 1, \dots, k\}$.
If we restrict the domain of $f \circ g|_K:K \to K$ to coincide with its image, then it is a bijection. By the above analysis, there are

$$k! \left[ \frac{k!}{e} \right]$$

such maps. Of course, we can set the rest of $h$ in any way we like. That is, for each $x \in N \setminus K$ we can choose $h(x) \in K$ arbitrarily. Thus, there are 
$$k! \left[ \frac{k!}{e} \right] \cdot (n-k)^k $$
pairs. We're not done though, since we began by making a choice of $Im h$. Let's sum over every possible such choice
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} k! \left[ \frac{k!}{e} \right] \cdot (n-k)^k $$

Comment: As I understand the question, $f$ and $g$ need not be bijections. Pastafarianist counts the total number of “situations” as $(n^n)^2$, which is the number of pairs of functions with no requirement that they’re bijections. It would be $(n!)^2$ if they were bijections. I’m still intrigued by the fact that the probability of exactly one fixed point seems to be $\dfrac{1}{e}$, but I’m not sure how your comment elucidates that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I totally misread. --I (hopefully) have fixed now.-- Okay, today is not my day. Still false