# Does this really converge to 1/e? (Massaging a sum)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, special-functions, binomial-coefficients

Short version: can we prove that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}^2 \frac{k!}{n^{2k}} \to \frac1e$$
as $n \to \infty$?

---

Long version: First, consider
$$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$
It is well-known that $a_n \to \dfrac1e$ as $n \to \infty$; indeed $a_n = \dfrac{!n}{n!}$ is the truncation to the first $n$ terms of the power series for $e^x$, evaluated at $x = -1$ (where $!n$ denotes the subfactorial; it is also equal to the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) on $n$ elements). There is also a simple expression for the generating function $A(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$, which is $A(z) = \dfrac{e^{-z}}{1-z}$. (See [Exponential Generating Functions For Derangements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240357/exponential-generating-functions-for-derangements/).)

Next, consider
$$b_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n^{\underline k}}{n^k} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$
where $n^{\underline k} = \binom{n}{k}k!$ denotes a falling factorial, so the extra factor $\frac{n^{\underline k}}{n^k}$ is $\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{n(n)\cdots(n)} = 1\cdot\left(1 - \frac1n\right)\cdot\left(1 - \frac2n\right)\cdots\left(1 - \frac{k-1}n\right)$ which for large $n$ (and fixed $k$) is close to $1$. 
I don't know if $b_n$ has a simple form for its generating function too, but it is easy to see that $b_n \to \dfrac1e$ as well; indeed by the binomial theorem we have $b_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (\frac{-1}{n})^k = \left(1 - \frac1n \right)^n$ which is well-known to converge to $\frac1e$ (indeed such a limit is sometimes taken to be the *definition* of $e^x$).

Finally, consider
$$c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n^{\underline k}}{n^k} \frac{n^{\underline k}}{n^k} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$

This is the same transformation going from $b_n$ to $c_n$ as from $a_n$ to $b_n$. But can we prove that $c_n \to \frac1e$ too? (And can we write down its generating function compactly, perchance?) More generally, what techniques exist that help in proving something about $\sum t_n s_n$, given $\sum s_n$?

This question arose from an attempt to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713370/an-unexpected-application-of-non-trivial-combinatorics/722961#722961), where I arrived at the expression $c_n$ above (there I called it $P_{n, n, 0}$; next I'll try to understand $P_{m, w, k}$).

[Note: I'm tagging this [special-functions](/questions/tagged/special-functions) too, as I understand $c_n$ has something to do with hypergeometric functions / Bessel functions / something like that.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly.

For any sequence of real numbers $(\alpha_n)_{n\geq 0}$ and $p\in\mathbb N$ let us denote by $(\alpha_n^{*p})$ (awkward notation) the sequence defined by 
$$\alpha_n^{*p}=\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{n^{\underline k}}{n^k}\right)^p \alpha_k\, . $$

Then, the following holds true: *for any absolutely convergent series $\sum\alpha_k$, the sequence $(\alpha_n^{*p})_{n\geq 0}$ is convergent with limit $\sum_0^\infty\alpha_k$.* In particular, with $\alpha_k=\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$ and $p=2$ you get that $c_n\to1/e$.

To see this, note that one can write 
$$\alpha_n^{*p}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty q_{n,k}\, \alpha_k\, ,$$
where 
$$q_{n,k}=\left\{ \begin{matrix}
\left(\frac{n^{\underline k}}{n^k}\right)^p&k\leq n\\0&k>n
\end{matrix}\right. $$

For each fixed $k$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} q_{n,k}=1$ by the formula for $\frac{n^{\underline k}}{n^k}$ you give in your question. Moreover, since $0\leq q_{n,k}\leq 1$ by the same formula, we also have $\vert q_{n,k}\alpha_k\vert\leq \vert\alpha_k\vert$ for all $n$ and every $k\geq 0$. By the dominated convergence theorem (for series), it follows that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^\infty q_{n,k}\alpha_k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\alpha_k\, , $$
which is the required result.

Comment: Thanks, "dominated convergence theorem (for series)" is what I was missing. (By the way, a minor note on simplifying notation: $n^{\underline k}$ turns out to be $0$ for $k > n$ (because there's a $(n-n)$ term in the falling factorial — alternatively note that $\binom{n}{k}k! = 0$ as $\binom{n}{k} = 0$ for $k > n$), so we don't really need a case-by-case definition of $q_{n,k}$. But perhaps it makes it clearer.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thanks for the note on the simplifying notation. Still, I think I'll leave the case-by-case definition.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm answering my own question, to reflect what I've understood from user Etienne's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/726586/205).)

The relevant tool is the **dominated convergence theorem for series** (sums). There are references [here](http://www.math.hmc.edu/~krieger/analysisresults.pdf) and [here](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/231-02-03/Lecture_Notes/chap2-3.pdf), among others. It says that

> if for every $k$, we have $f_n(k) \to f(k)$ as $n \to \infty$, and
>   further each of the sequences $f_n$ is dominated by some summable
>   sequence $g$ (that is $|f_n(k)| \le g(k)$ for all $n$ and $k$ where
>   $\sum_{k} g(k)$ exists), then 
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_k f_n(k) = \sum_{k} \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(k) = \sum_k f(k)$$

(I've intentionally left out the "types" of $k$, $f$, $f_n$, etc., to keep the statement concise and because the theorem is applicable broadly.)

In particular, suppose we know that a particular sequence $s_k$ has series sum $\sum_{k \ge 0} s_k = S$. Suppose further that $t_{m,k}$ is a sequence of tweaking/tempering factors, such that $|t_{m,k}| \le 1$, and $\lim_{m \to \infty} t_{m,k} = 1$ for all $k$. Then,
$$\lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{k \ge 0} t_{m,k} s_k = \sum_{k\ge0} \lim_{m\to\infty} t_{m,k} s_k = \sum_{k\ge 0} s_k = S.$$

Thus multiplying the $k$th term $s_k$ by $t_{m,k}$ (which in the limit is $1$) does not affect the sum in the limit.

What we have here is a particular case with $t_{m,k} = \dfrac{m^{\underline k}}{m^k}\dfrac{m^{\underline k}}{m^k}$, which clearly goes to $1$, and therefore the sum (for the particular $s_k$'s in the question) remains $1/e$.